# NFS with autofs: mounting /run/lock gives permissions error

Tags: nfs, autofs

I'm running Ubuntu server 14.04 as an NFS server to another 14.04 machine (one's a mail server the other a web server where I'd like to run the MailMan admin GUI). I'm using autofs to mount the exports on the other side:

In my /etc/exports I have the following:

```
/etc/mailman        10.10.10.102(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
/usr/lib/mailman    10.10.10.102(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
/var/lib/mailman    10.10.10.102(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
/run/lock/mailman   10.10.10.102(fsid=1,rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

On the client, I have an auto.master file with:

```
/net    /etc/auto.net
```

and the auto.net script has the following:

```
opts="-fstype=nfs4,hard,intr,nodev,suid,async"
```

The first three all turn up as mounts on the other machine (under /net/10.10.10.103/) and I can use them fine.

The problem is that the last one appears, but the final directory beneath it gives me permission denied errors. I suspect this is because it's a lock directory, but don't know what that might mean for NFS:

```
root@alice:/# ls /net/10.10.10.103/run/lock/
mailman
```

```
root@alice:/# ls /net/10.10.10.103/run/lock/mailman/
ls: cannot access /net/10.10.10.103/run/lock/mailman/: No such file or directory
```

On the server I have the following in /etc/default/nfs-common (and similar on the client)

```
NEED_STATD=1 (because I'm using nfs3?)
STATDOPTS="-n 10.10.10.103"
NEED_GSSD=
```

How can I get /run/lock/mailman to export with the same permissions as it has on the server?

---

**EDIT**: I think this may be because /run/lock is on tmpfs on the server. /proc/mounts shows:

```
none /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k,nr_inodes=567757 0 0
```

I see that /run/lock/mailman is replicated as /var/lock/mailman though, which isn't tmpfs. However, when I try to export /var/lock/mailman it exports as /run/lock/mailman anyway.

Does NFS not export from tmpfs or something?

Comment: Having earned the "tumbleweed" badge on this question, I think I'm going to just ditch MailMan and use some other mailing list software instead. It may not be MailMan that's the problem of course, but the UI is ugly and it's all a bit 1998.